# Adding .cu and .cuh as 'c' code in Git Extensions

Tags: git, cuda, git-extensions

I'm looking at the lines of code estimate given in Git Extensions and I don't think it is counting the .cu and .cuh CUDA lines of code in those files.

How do I add the .cu and .cuh file extensions into the various Git Gui and Git Extensions tools?

Is there a special file I have to add *.cu and *.cuh into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like something that is specific to *Git Extensions*, not Git itself (Git cares very little about file types<sup>1</sup>).

I have not used *Git Extensions*, but a look through the [source code](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions) turned up a [likely candidate for the default list of extensions](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/blob/e80571585bf2c6b42f3e08be6587a6fbdc2c3ac6/Plugins/Statistics/GitStatistics/GitStatisticsPlugin.cs#L20) used in the [statistics plugin](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/blob/e80571585bf2c6b42f3e08be6587a6fbdc2c3ac6/Plugins/Statistics/GitStatistics/). It looks like this is *intended* to be configurable, but I have not investigated the code enough to find out if it actually *is* configurable. Maybe it is only [configurable through the registry](https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions/blob/e80571585bf2c6b42f3e08be6587a6fbdc2c3ac6/GitExtensions/GitPluginSettingsContainer.cs#L18)? (somewhere under `CurrentUser\Software\ GitExtensions\GitExtensions\<version>`?)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Git does include a default set of “diff drivers” (and lets you define other such drivers) that locate the text to use after each “hunk header” (`@@ -k,l +n,m @@` line) and how to break up words in “word diff” mode. Diff drivers are assigned via attribute (`.gitattributes`, `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes`, or (in Git 1.7.4 and later) `/etc/gitattributes`, or the file named by the `core.attributesfile` configuration variable), but they are not strictly based on extensions themselves (though that is, effectively, how most attributes are assigned in practice).

Comment: That's useful in helping to sort the problem - It was the Statitsics plug in that hinted at the problem, [which I also see in Visual Studio .. don't have an answer for that either :-[

Comment: Adding the `;*.cu;*.cuh` to the end of the registry entry did it for the Git Extensions Plug-in - Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit list of code files extensions in Plugins > Settings > Statistics

Answer (score 0):

Check your .gitingore file and your .gitexcludes.

Comment: The cu and cuh files are being included in the repo, it's just the statistics, and possibly the diff that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the exact path of the registry entry has not yet been posted here, I'll do it now:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\GitExtensions\GitExtensions\StatisticsCode files`